# (Unity3D) How to put note or documentation on script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unity3d-editor

:) Is there a way for us to set a **note** or a **documentation** that can be displayed on the *Inspector* view under a custom script we've made?

[image: Please see the image for a sample.]

Answer (score 3):

This answer isn't mine, it's from a [link that I found on google](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1019430/show-a-warning-in-the-inspector.html).

> You have to implement a custom inspector for your class and when you want to show such a warning you can use `EditorGUILayout.HelpBox` inside `OnInspectorGUI`.
>
> Something like that:
>
> `EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Some warning text", MessageType.Warning);`

The [`MessageType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/353/Documentation/ScriptReference/MessageType.html) parameter for [`EditorGUILayout.HelpBox`](https://docs.unity3d.com/353/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.HelpBox.html) has multiple options, one of which is `Info`, which seems suitable for displaying a note, rather than a warning.

And here's a [second link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/926391/how-to-add-notes-in-inspector.html) which gives more information.

Comment: Since it's just a function call you don't have to quote anyone or provide a link. If tat's a long code written by another person from another website then you should quote and link them too. Although your last link is helpful.

Comment: @Programmer I have to admit, what drove me to put that disclaimer in was that I was too lazy to rewrite what I found in my own words ;)

Comment: @Zarashi99 please don't forget to accept this answer because it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `Tooltip`attribute is sufficient. It allows you to document your public fields so that a tooltip popup is shown on mouse over.
s. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TooltipAttribute.html for more information.

**[Update]**
I found a better way to achieve this out of the box (still not perfect).
The [Header attribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HeaderAttribute.html) allows you to show text directly in the inspector, but there is no way to include rich text formatting or images

```
    [Header("--- Note ---", order=1)]
    [Space(-10, order = 2)]
    [Header("First Attribute is between 1 and 10", order = 3)]
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public int FirstProperty = 1;

    [Space(10, order = 4)]
    public string Hint;
```

looks like
[image: Inspector view]